# Session gone in Integration Tests in Rails 2.3.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, session-state

In Rails 2.3.8 my integration tests (after considerable work, and the help of [this post](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/get-session-in-rails-integration-test/)) were able to make use of a single session across requests.  In Rails 2.3.10, that functionality broke, and after logging in, subsequent requests have no session.

One possible symptom is that this bit of code used to pass:

```
open_session do |s|
 s.post 'login', :user=>{:user_name=>username, :password=>pass}
 assert_not_nil(s.session[:id])
end
```

And now it fails (s.session[:id] is nil).  This may or may not be *the* problem, as I can confirm that other variables stored in the session during the login action are present.  However on subsequent s.post's, the actions all report that there's nothing in the session.

Any advice? I saw one report that Rails 2.3.9 introduced a session bug with [this](http://gist.github.com/570149) as the workaround, but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's driving me crazy!!!! I can't figure out how in the heck this would happen.

Comment: Did you end up finding a fix for this? Just tried to upgrade 2.3.5 -> 2.3.14 and ran into the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `s.session.data[:id]`